# GAMESS config script error on bash: syntax error near $<

Tags: linux, bash, shell, compilation, sh

Error I get is following:

After the new window is open, please hit enter to go on../config: line 82: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./config: line 82:`set reply=$<'

I'm in bash shell. The script was originally meant for csh. I've changed the first line of the script to #!/bin/bash.

The script is supposed to open a new window to enter some variables for configuring. 
.
.
.

```
echo "use the word 'type' to indicate it is a command for the other window."
echo " "
echo -n "After the new window is open, please hit enter to go on."
set reply=$<
tput clear
```

I've checked and know that the shell is interactive. Instead of executing with sh ./config I tried with bash ./config ; still same error. if I type < in the shell I get the same error. So I figured that make cannot understand '<' 
I'm at my wits end googling for the error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There seems to be some confusion between backtick and single-quote in line 82 that you quoted. Also, you don't need the angle bracket or `set` to set that variable. Try `read REPLY`; the user's input will be available in `$REPLY`.

Comment: $<' is just how the error is shown.. set reply=$< is the actual code. The config script worked a few years ago in a different machine configuration (different cluster). There are numerous 'set reply..' in the config script. I'm not supposed to change the script. I'm assuming I have something like a wrong environment setting.

Comment: it's really unlikely that the original `csh` script will work, unmodified, in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to meatspace! I abandoned the idea of 'fixing' but just get it running.
What worked was running the script while I'm in tcsh - no edits needed in the script. Since I only needed to set everything for the configuration file it didn't matter how the config script generated the actual installation script. 
After that is generated I just switched to bash and everything worked.